# Where can I find out which BIP (bitcoin improvement proposal) are going to be implemented or not?

Tags: bip

Is there a site where I can see which BIP's are going to be implemented or not?

Answer (score 2):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Improvement_Proposals

BIPs aren't too organized, but usually there's a thread in the development section of bitcointalk and a few things on mailing list.